# Office fabric ui Server side rendering in a node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, office-fabric

I'm making a single `MERN` app for training and i though use `Office Frabric UI` could be a good idea.

I'm using server side rendering for my app but i am getting this error when i use a single `<Fabric>` component:

```
/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@microsoft/load-themed-styles/lib/index.js:277
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
               ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at registerStyles (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@microsoft/load-themed-styles/lib/..\src/index.ts:390:33)
    at applyThemableStyles (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@microsoft/load-themed-styles/lib/..\src/index.ts:243:7)
    at /home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@microsoft/load-themed-styles/lib/..\src/index.ts:183:7
    at measure (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@microsoft/load-themed-styles/lib/..\src/index.ts:121:3)
    at Object.loadStyles (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@microsoft/load-themed-styles/lib/..\src/index.ts:167:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/@uifabric/utilities/src/scroll.scss.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Tutorials/full-stack-js-lynda/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the problem.

Ok, i see in the ["documentation"](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react#server-side-rendering) steps for server-side rendering:

1. I put this in my `serverRender` file:

   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
   import axios from 'axios';
   import { configureLoadStyles } from '@microsoft/load-themed-styles';

   import App from './src/components/app';
   import config from './config';

   const getApiUrl = contestId => {
     if (contestId) {
       return `${config.serverUrl}/api/contests/${contestId}`;
     }
     return `${config.serverUrl/api/contests}`;
   };

   const getInitialData = (contestId, apiData) => {
     if (contestId) {
       return {
         currentContestId: apiData.id,
         contests: {
           [apiData.id]: apiData
         }
       };
     }
     return {
       contests: apiData.contests
     };
   };

   const serverRender = (contestId) =>
     axios.get(getApiUrl(contestId))
       .then(resp => {
         let _allStyles = '';
         const initialData = getInitialData(contestId, resp.data);
         configureLoadStyles((styles: string) => {
           _allStyles += styles;
         });

   ```
     return {
       initialMarkup: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
         <App initialData={initialData} />
       ),
       initialData,
       styles: _allStyles
     };
   });
   ```

   export default serverRender;
2. And this for my `server` file:

   import config from './config';
   import apiRouter from './api';
   import serverRender from './serverRender';

   // import sassMiddleware from 'node-sass-middleware';
   import path from 'path';
   import express from 'express';

   const server = express();

   /*
   server.use(sassMiddleware({
     src: path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
     dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
   }));
   */

   server.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   server.get(['/', '/contests/:contestId'], (req, res) => {
     serverRender(req.params.contestId)
       .then(({ initialMarkup, initialData, styles }) => {
         res.render('index', {
           initialMarkup, initialData
         });
         red.render('header', {
           styles
         });
       })
       .catch(console.error);
   });

   server.use('/api', apiRouter);
   server.use(express.static('public'));

   server.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
     console.info('Express listening on port: ', config.port);
   });
3. And finally in my `header` file:

   Naming Contests

   <%- styles -%>

And it still doesn't works.

Which is the properly from to SSR with `Office Fabric UI`?

Comment: The `document` object doesn't work when you're working with Node. It only works when there's an HTML file (Only in a frontend, though). I could be wrong, shrug.